# How to connect ASP.NET Core 5 MVC project to Supabase database instead of SQL Server?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, supabase, supabase-database

I'm new to developing Dot Net projects and I've spent most of my time developing small projects with React, Next.js, and Vue.js alongside Supabase for the database.

In the `ConfigureServices` method, I see tutorials use `options => options.UseSqlServer`:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
    services.AddControllersWithViews().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
}
```

What is the proper way to do the same thing but with Supabase?

I downloaded the nuget package https://www.nuget.org/packages/supabase-csharp/

but I don't see any documentation on how to use this in the `ConfigureServices` method.

Thank you all for your advice!

Comment: By using the correct EF Core provider. Does it even have one? The package you linked to is used *instead* of EF Core. If you used PostgreSQL you could use the NpgSQL EF Core provider. Since Supabase is actually a hosted service though, you can't use that.

Answer (score 1):

This is the [documentation](https://github.com/supabase-community/supabase-csharp) for **supabase** and I don't think this can be configured in configure services. Because you are using **dbContext** which  is related to Entity framework if there is a package for entity framework which have support for it than you can do the following.

Comment: Thank you for looking into this. I was finally able to connect to Supabase. I had to remind myself what kind of DB Supabase is - it's a PostgreSQL. I just downloaded the NpgSql nuget package and followed along the steps listed here - https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/index.html
The end result was this -
```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Other DI initializations

    services.AddDbContext<BloggingContext>(options =>
            options.UseNpgsql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("BloggingContext")));
}
```

Comment: No problem hoped it helped.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it with one line of code
in Program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<Context>(options => options.UseNpgsql(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("Connection")));
```

"Connection" that come from appsettings.json you can find yours connection in your supabase account settings and pales it in appsettings.json

supabase had postgresql database not sqlserver